# Replace space with Pipe between the tags

Tags: text-processing, files

I have a file that is coming in tags "{}". Need to convert it into a pipe format.

Here is the sample:

```
{Id USXXXXXX} {Code USXXXXX} {Desc abcd 6.000% 5/24}
```

Expected result 1:

```
{Id|USXXXXXX} {Code|USXXXXX} {Desc|abcd 6.000% 5/24}
```

Expected result 2:

```
Id|USXXXXXX|Code|USXXXXX|Desc|abcd 6.000% 5/24
```

Answer (score 1):

How will these work for you?

```
awk '{for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) {if ($i ~ /^{/) {printf("%s|", $i)} else {printf("%s ", $i)}} printf("\n")}' test.in
```

for expected result 1, and

```
awk '{for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) {if ($i ~ /^{/) {printf("%s|", $i)} else {printf("%s ", $i)}} printf("\n")}' test.in | sed -e 's#^{##' -e 's#} {#|#g' -e 's#} $##'
```

for expected result 2.

Comment: Glad they work for you.  Please remember to like the answer, and mark it as an answer if you find it acceptable.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try also

```
awk -F"{" '{for (i=2; i<=NF; i++) sub (" ", "|", $i)}1' OFS="{" file
{Id|USXXXXXX} {Code|USXXXXX} {Desc|abcd 6.000% 5/24}
```

and

```
awk -F"{" '{gsub (/}( |$)/, ""); for (i=2; i<=NF; i++) sub (" ", "|", $i); sub (/\|/, "")}1' OFS="|" file
Id|USXXXXXX|Code|USXXXXX|Desc|abcd 6.000% 5/24
```

Answer (score 0):

For result 1 below is the command

```
@praveen_2 ~]# echo "{Id USXXXXXX} {Code USXXXXX} {Desc abcd 6.000% 5/24}"| sed "s/{[A-Za-z]\{2,\}/&|/g"
```

output

```
{Id| USXXXXXX} {Code| USXXXXX} {Desc| abcd 6.000% 5/24}
```

For result2 below is the command

```
echo "{Id USXXXXXX} {Code USXXXXX} {Desc abcd 6.000% 5/24}"| sed "s/\}//g"| sed 's/ {/|/g'| sed 's/^{//g'| sed 's/ [a-zA-Z]\{2,\}/|&/g'
```

output

```
Id| USXXXXXX|Code| USXXXXX|Desc| abcd 6.000% 5/24
```